# Java regex to match french floating point number don't matchin blank space

Tags: java, regex, formatting, internationalization, numbers

I'm writing a simple validation for BigDecimal numbers in english, spanish and french. I want to accept plain numbers like (1234.56 or 1234,56 depending on decimal separator's locale) and formatted numbers (1,234.56 fro english, 1.234.56 for spanish, or 1 234,56 for french). I've done this with english and spanish and i've successfully tested it, but it fails with french.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.println( "es 1.234.567,89 : " + "1.234.567,89".matches("(((\\d{1,3})([.]\\d{3})*)|(\\d+))([,]\\d+)?") );
    System.out.println( "en 1,234,567.89 : " + "1,234,567.89".matches("(((\\d{1,3})([,]\\d{3})*)|(\\d+))([.]\\d+)?") );
}
```

Output:

```
es 1.234.567,89 : true
en 1,234,567.89 : true
```

But when i try to do this with french grouping separator, validation falis.

```
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.println( "fr 1 234 567,89 : " + "1 234 567,89".matches("(((\\d{1,3})([ ]\\d{3})*)|(\\d+))([,]\\d+)?") );
}
```

Output:

```
fr 1 234 567,89 : false
```

This also fails:

```
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.println( "fr 1 234 567,89 : " + "1 234 567,89".matches("(((\\d{1,3})(\\s\\d{3})*)|(\\d+))([,]\\d+)?") );
}
```

Output:

```
fr 1 234 567,89 : false
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't want to use "NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("es")).parse(str) ); because it parses correctly 6,1 as 6.1 but parses 6.1 as 61.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a regex that matches all your formats precisely.

```
^\d{1,3}(?:([., ])?\d{3})?(?:\1\d{3})*(?:(?!\1)[,.]\d+)?$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` --> Matches start of string
- `\d{1,3}` --> Matches one to three digits
- `(?:([., ])?\d{3})?` --> Here `([., ])` captures either a dot, comma or space and puts in group 1 for backreference for not allowing it as decimal number delimiter and this character set is optional so as to match plain version of numbers. Secondly `\d{3}` follows three digit numbers and whole of this group is optional to match whole numbers that doesn't have any dot, comma or space.
- `(?:\1\d{3})*` --> This part is for matching dot, comma or space, whatever got captured in group1 followed by three digits and this can recur zero or more times.
- `(?:(?!\1)[,.]\d+)?` --> Finally this captures the decimal part where negative look ahead `(?!\1)` doesn't allow what was captured in group1 but allow either a comma or dot followed by one or more digits that will be part of decimal
- `$` --> Matches end of input

It matches,

```
1.234.567,89
1.234.567
1.234
24
1234.56
1234
1,234,567.89
1 234 567,89
1 234 567,89
```

And does not match,

```
1.234.567.89
12.234.
1,234,567,89
1,234.567.89
1 234.567,89
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/b73VPS/3)**

Your Java code,

```
System.out.println("es 1.234.567,89 : "
        + "1.234.567,89".matches("^\\d{1,3}(?:([., ])\\d{3})?(?:\\1\\d{3})*(?:(?!\\1)[,.]\\d+)?$"));
System.out.println("en 1,234,567.89 : "
        + "1,234,567.89".matches("^\\d{1,3}(?:([., ])\\d{3})?(?:\\1\\d{3})*(?:(?!\\1)[,.]\\d+)?$"));
System.out.println("fr 1 234 567,89 : "
        + "1 234 567,89".matches("^\\d{1,3}(?:([., ])\\d{3})?(?:\\1\\d{3})*(?:(?!\\1)[,.]\\d+)?$"));
System.out.println("fr 1 234 567,89 : "
        + "1 234 567,89".matches("^\\d{1,3}(?:([., ])\\d{3})?(?:\\1\\d{3})*(?:(?!\\1)[,.]\\d+)?$"));
System.out.println("1234.56: "
        + "1 234 567,89".matches("^\\d{1,3}(?:([., ])\\d{3})?(?:\\1\\d{3})*(?:(?!\\1)[,.]\\d+)?$"));
System.out.println("1234: "
        + "1 234 567,89".matches("^\\d{1,3}(?:([., ])\\d{3})?(?:\\1\\d{3})*(?:(?!\\1)[,.]\\d+)?$"));
```

Prints,

```
es 1.234.567,89 : true
en 1,234,567.89 : true
fr 1 234 567,89 : true
fr 1 234 567,89 : true
1234.56: true
1234: true
```

Comment: Good solution! but it does not cover the plain (unformatted) version of the numbers: 1234.56 or 1234,56; anyway i think i can handle myselft to adapt it to my requirements.

Comment: I didn't knew if you wanted to cover them as that. Let me update my regex to cover that as well.

Comment: On the other hand, i don't understand why (((\\d{1,3})([ ]\\d{3})*)|(\\d+))([,]\\d+)? is not matching the white space as (((\\d{1,3})([.]\\d{3})*)|(\\d+))([,]\\d+)? or (((\\d{1,3})([,]\\d{3})*)|(\\d+))([.]\\d+)? matches correctly the dot and the comma

Comment: For me your `(((\\d{1,3})([ ]\\d{3})*)|(\\d+))([,]\\d+)?` pattern matches. See this, `System.out.println("fr 1 234 567,89 : "
    + "1 234 567,89".matches("(((\\d{1,3})([ ]\\d{3})*)|(\\d+))([,]\\d+)?"));` prints true

Comment: @CarlosNúñezGarcía: Updated my regex for handling plain version of numbers like you wanted. Just had to make first character set optional. `([., ])` to `([., ])?`

Comment: I've just discovered a really weird thing:

 public static void main(final String[] args) {
  System.out.println( "fr 1 234 567,89 : " + "1 234 567,89".matches("(((\\d{1,3})([ ]\\d{3})*)|(\\d+))([,]\\d+)?") );
  System.out.println( "fr 1 234 567,89 : " + "1 234 567,89".matches("(((\\d{1,3})([ ]\\d{3})*)|(\\d+))([,]\\d+)?"));
 }

returns: false and true. WTF!

Maybe a encoding issue? I'm investigating it... Anyway, thank you very much!!!

Comment: For me it prints true and true. Your both sysouts are identical so they both have to print same. May be some weird issue in your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You could use java.text.NumberFormat it already has the rules built in for different locales.

```
    System.out.println( NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH).parse("123,456.56") );
    System.out.println( NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH).parse("123 456,56") );
    System.out.println( NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("es-es")).parse("123.456,56") );
```

Comment: System.out.println( NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH).parse("123 456,56") ); prints 123.